# C# select only specific values from a list of items

Tags: c#

Starting with C#, I came across the following the problem:

I have a class called `SomeValue` with the definition:

```
public class SomeValue{
     public decimal Close { get; set; }
     public int Bar { get; set; }
     public DateTime Time { get; set; }
     public SomeValue(decimal close, int bar, DateTime time) {
         Close = close;
         Bar = bar;
         Time = time;
     }
 }
```

Later on, I have a series of `SomeValue` items and want to take the `Close` value up until some threshold:

```
var ydata = series.TakeWhile(x => x.Close == maxItem.Close).ToList();
```

How do I get only the `Close` Values?

Comment: As in, you want to _select_ only the `Close` property from each element of the `ydata` collection, and throw away the rest of the `SomeValue` object?

Comment: @gunr2171: Exactly.